# Data.Frames in Python Numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dataframe

How do I build data.frames containing multiple types of data(Strings, int, logical) and both continuous and factors in Python Numpy?

The following code makes my headers NaN's and all but my float values Nan's

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('FlightDataTraining.csv', delimiter=',')
```

This puts a "b'data'" on all of my data, such that year becomes "b'year'"

```
import numpy as np
d = np.loadtxt('FlightDataTraining.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=str)
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at  [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1):

- Try `genfromtxt('FlightDataTraining.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)`. This tells `genfromtxt` to intelligently guess the dtype of each column. If that does not work, please post a sample of your CSV and what the desired output should look like.
- The `b` in `b'data'` is Python's way of representing [`bytes` as opposed to `str` objects](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#byte-arrays). So the `b'data'` is okay. If you want `str`s, you would need to decode the bytes.
- NumPy does not have a  dtype for representing factors, though [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) does have a [`pd.Categorical` type](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html).

Comment: Great answer. I would only suggest that you add the `skip_header` to the `genfromtxt` call. @user3711518 says that he/she has problems with the headers. If `dtype=None`, the headers will force all the columns to be interpreted as strings instead of the data's type.